# PHP preg_replace BESbswy ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

is it possible to match this string with using regex? The whole string is wrapped with p tags and last 2 with strong tags.

BESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswy
**BESbswy**
**BESbswy**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is,
something like this

```
<?php $string = '<p>BESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswy<strong>BESbswy</strong><strong>BESbswy</strong></p>' ?>

<?= preg_replace('|<p>BESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswy<strong>BESbswy</strong><strong>BESbswy</strong></p>|','aa',$string) ?>
```